# Order by the same grouped column mutiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to order some Item by many Tags, extracting distinct Item ids, 
the data are like these:

Sample Data

```
Item:
 id    name    creation
 1     item1    2017-06-26 16:48:54
 2     item2    2017-06-23 16:48:54
 3     item3    2017-06-29 16:49:42
 4     item4    2017-06-15 16:50:31
 5     item5    2017-06-09 16:50:44
 6     item6    2017-06-12 16:50:57

 ItemTag:
 id    priority
 1     10
 2     999
 3     15
 4     8

ItemHasItemTag:
itemId   itemTagId
1        1
1        2
2        1
2        3
3        4
4        1
4        4
5        1
5        2
5        3
6        2
```

i want to extract the Item id ordered by the ItemTag priority ASC,
with a query similar to this **WRONG** one:

```
SELECT i.id,
  group_concat(it.priority order by priority asc) as tagPriorities
FROM Item i
  JOIN ItemHasItemTag ihit on i.id = ihit.itemId
  JOIN ItemTag it on it.id = ihit.tagId
GROUP BY i.id
ORDER BY it.priority asc;
```

result:

```
itemId   (tagPriorities)
3        8
1        10,999
2        10,15
4        8,10
5        10,15,999
6        999
```

the result that i want should be be this:

```
itemId    (tagPriorities)
3         8
4         8,10
2         10,15
5         10,15,999
1         10,999
6         999
```

Of course since the group by is executed **before** the order by, it messes up the order

Can someone help me?

i attach the creation schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `creation` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE 
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ItemTag` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ItemHasItemTag` (
  `itemId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tagId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`itemId`,`tagId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Item` (`id`, `name`, `creation`) VALUES
  (1, 'item1', '2017-06-26 16:48:54'),(2, 'item2', '2017-06-23 16:48:54'),(3, 'item3', '2017-06-29 16:49:42'),(4, 'item4', '2017-06-15 16:50:31'),(5, 'item5', '2017-06-09 16:50:44'),(6, 'item6', '2017-06-12 16:50:57');

INSERT INTO `ItemTag` (`id`, `priority`) VALUES
  (1, 10),(2, 999),(3, 15),(4, 8);

INSERT INTO `ItemHasItemTag` (`itemId`, `tagId`) VALUES
  (1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 1),(2, 3),(3, 4),(4, 1),(4, 4),(5, 1),(5, 2),(5, 3),(6, 2);
```

Comment: that is a "wanted resoult" that i can't get, it's not the resoult of the query, i'll edit the question to specify it

Comment: Fixed, i will not need the (tagPriorities) for the final result, but i want the ids ordered by those, so i added them to check the result

Comment: Great. Got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this get you what you want?

```
select
    itempri.itemid
from (
    select
        ihit.itemid,
        min(it.priority) as pri
    from
        itemhasitemtag as ihit
        inner join itemtag as it on it.id=ihit.itemid
    group by
        ihit.itemid
    ) as itempri
order by
    pri;
```

EDIT:

To order by all the priorities in ascending order, you might want something like this:

```
select
    ihit.itemid,
    group_concat(lpad(cast(it.priority as character(8), 8, '0')), order by it.priority separator ', ') as pristr
from
    itemhasitemtag as ihit
    inner join itemtag as it on it.id=ihit.itemid
group by
    ihit.itemid
order by
    pristr;
```

(untested)

Comment: no, also because in this way i only take into consideration the minimum priority: the items 2,5,1 have the same minimum: 10, the query won't order by the second value (15,15,999)

Comment: i thought about lpad to normalize the group_concat just now (after a day of headache), i tested it and it works,so i will accept your answer. Still, i wonder if there is a cleaner solution, THANKS!

Comment: @Nemolo Nothing wrong with accepting an answer if it solves the problem, but note that we tend to lose interest once an answer's been accepted.

Comment: @Nemolo - Depending on the distribution of priority values that could be assigned (which I presume you know or maybe can control) you might be able to define an algorithm to order multiple priorities, such as the sum of the inverse of the priorities (or inverse of the squares, or priority times the inverse of the priority rank).  Of course, such a solution also depends on what you consider 'clean'.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the advice, in fact i'm curious about a cleaner answer but i think that the question is tricky, and i'm happy to have at least a working solution even if is not a perfect one.

Comment: @rd_nielsen i would consider cleaner a query without tricks, a way to preserve the order of Priorities while grouping by. In fact if you don't group by, you will have duplicate results, but perfectly ordered